# Query giving error

Tags: sql-server, runtime-error

The below query is giving error, please help me.

```
declare     @dateScorecard datetime
set @dateScorecard = convert(varchar, 4)+'/1/'+ convert(varchar,2013)
select @dateScorecard
select top 1 i_CurrentMonthColor from AK_ScoreCardDetails scr
where datediff(m, convert(Datetime, convert(varchar, 4)+'/1/'+ convert(varchar,2013)), @dateScorecard)
```

error details:

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick comments:

First, you don't need to use convert on those numbers--just put them right into your query, i.e.

```
set @dateScoreCard = convert('4/1/2013');
```

Also, in the 'where' clause, you are not comparing the result of the datediff to anything There should be a section after the datediff clause, i.e.:

```
where datediff(.....) > 2
```

for example. Your `datediff` function only gives you a number that is the difference of the two dates you gave it, in the terms you define, which is months here. Use that number to compare to some value you want to make your sql statement work for you.